# Where are the dummy collaborators in in-memory documents?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/in-memory) suggests that there would be dummy data populating the results from calling `getCollaborators`, although it does not give any details about what the dummy data would look like.

My calls to `getCollaborators` return an empty list. It would be quite helpful to populate the list with one dummy collaborator which `isMe` so that I don't have to check `document.isInGoogleDrive` all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been added to the API. It should be available in about a week.